# Add time stamp to end of file name before upload to ftp

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using the following function to upload mp4 file to ftp

```
 def run(self):
        while True:
            status = "Failed"
            #logger.debug("Queue size: %s" %(str(self.queue.qsize())))
            (env, pfile) = self.queue.get()
            logger.debug("Thread %s Received %s and %s" %(str(self.threadID), pfile, env))
            metaName = "%s/%s.evs.xml" %(self.config[env]["upload_folder"], pfile)
            mediaName = "%s/%s.mp4" %(self.config[env]["upload_folder"], pfile)
        mediaName2 = "%s.mp4" %(pfile,)     
            logger.info("Thread %s - Uploading metadata to %s FTP: %s" %(str(self.threadID), env, metaName))
            try:
                ur = uploadFTPMP(metaName, env)
        status = "Success"
            except:
                logger.debug("Thread %s - Uploading of metadata %s to %s failed" %(str(self.threadID), metaName, env))
                uploadComplete(pfile, status, env)
            if status == "Success": 
                logger.info("Thread %s - Sleeping to allow cms to pick up xml" %(str(self.threadID)))
                time.sleep(90)
                logger.info( "Thread %s - Uploading mediafile %s to %s" %(str(self.threadID), mediaName, env))
        ur = uploadFTP(mediaName, env)
                status = "Success"
        filename = os.path.basename(mediaName)
        http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
        logging.basicConfig()
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
        requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
        requests_log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        requests_log.propagate = True
        url = 'http://www.webdev.com/web/home/testPOST'
        headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
        payload = {'mediaName': mediaName2 ,'status': 'sucsses'}
        r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
        r.text
        r.status_code
            r.connection.close()
                uploadComplete(pfile, status, env)
            logger.info("Thread %s - Upload completed with status %s" %(str(self.threadID), status))
            self.queue.task_done()
```

I'm trying to modify the mp4 file before up, time stamp to end of the file so the file name will be `video-%H%M%S.mp4` then it will be uploaded.

Then, when I perform the post request, as you can see, it sends 2 parameters now, I need to add 3rd parameter which is the new name with time stamp. Any tips to achieve this logic?

Here is my ftp function also.

```
def uploadFTPMP(filepath, env):

    global config

    ftpsrv = config[env]["active"]
    ftpusr = config[env]["ftpuser"]
    ftppwd = config[env]["ftppass"]

    filename = os.path.basename(filepath)

    try:
        ftp = ftplib.FTP(ftpsrv)
        ftp.login(ftpusr, ftppwd)
    except:
        logger.error("Ftp connection error has occurred")
        raise 
    else:
        f = open(filepath, "r")
        cmd = "STOR %s" %(filename)
        out = ftp.storbinary(cmd, f)
        f.close()
        ftp.quit()
        return out
```

Answer (score 3):

You should pass the datetime to the filename.

```
import datetime

medianame = 'somefile_{timestamp}.mp4'.format(
    timestamp=datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
)
```

The datetime can also be formatted as you require e.g. `datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H%M')`. The [`strftime()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)  has a list of accepted formatting directives that can be used.